# Deciding the order of entire functions - conway exercise

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

[image]

This is an exercise from Conway. With some help I managed to solve (a), (b) and the first half of (c). However I am stuck with the second inequality of (c). I can't find a way to prove the inequality. Could anyone help me? Also could anyone give me a hint on how to solve (e)? I think I managed to solve (d).

Answer (score 2):

The second inequality of (c):

Note that $$
r^N\le r^{(2r)^{1/(\alpha -\varepsilon )}}
$$
and
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=p+1}^N\left(\frac{1}{n^{\alpha -\varepsilon }}\right)^n&\le \sum_{n=p+1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{n^{\alpha -\varepsilon }}\right)^n\le\sum_{n=p+1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{(p+1)^{\alpha -\varepsilon }}\right)^n\\
&\le \left(\frac{1}{(p+1)^{\alpha -\varepsilon }}\right)^{p+1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{(p+1)^{\alpha -\varepsilon }}\right)^n<\infty.
\end{align}
Hence we have $$
\sum_{n=p+1}^N\left(\frac{r}{n^{\alpha -\varepsilon }}\right)^n
<r^N \sum_{n=p+1}^N\left(\frac{1}{n^{\alpha -\varepsilon }}\right)^n<Br^{(2r)^{1/(\alpha -\varepsilon )}}=B\exp\left( (2r)^{1/(\alpha -\varepsilon )}\log r\right)
$$
where $$
B= \left(\frac{1}{(p+1)^{\alpha -\varepsilon }}\right)^{p+1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{(p+1)^{\alpha -\varepsilon }}\right)^n.
$$

Hint for part (e):
In part (a), from the inequality$$
\frac{-\log |c_n|}{n\log n}\ge \frac{1}{\beta }\left(1-\frac{1+\log \beta }{\log n}\right) 
$$
we can conclude not only $\alpha >0$ but also $\alpha \ge 1/\beta $. Tending $\beta $ to $\lambda $ we have $$
\lambda \ge \frac{1}{\alpha }.$$